# Batch file 'continue' to next iteration in FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm currently supporting a team of techs who are upgrading machines in offices and I need to keep track of the amount of machines that are online.

Currently what I have is a text file (OfficeName.txt) with a list of machine names, and a batch file (OfficeName.bat).

What I want to happen is for it to loop through the list of machines and ping them.
If the ping is successful, remove the name from the list and increment a counter by 1, if unsuccessful, then move on to the next machine in the list.

The issue I'm having is that if a machine's ping result comes back with "could not find host", it still sets the errorlevel to 0, so I can't use an IF/ELSE.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a counter=0
set "NVC="

for /F %%a in (%~n0.txt) do set "NVC=!NVC! %%a"

:ping
for %%i in (%NVC%) do (
    ping %%i -n 1 >nul | find "TTL=" >nul || echo. %%i is offline.
    set /a counter+=1
    echo %%i is online
    set "NVC=!NVC: %%i=!"
)
cls
echo. %counter% machines are online.
if defined NVC goto :ping

echo All machines in %~n0 are online.
pause
```

The problem is that once the "%%i is offline" line is done, it just continues to the next line and removes it anyway.

Is there a way to skip the 3 lines below the ping if the ping result is bad, and continue with the next iteration in the list?

Note: I'm running this from Server 2008, pinging Win 8.1 machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're trying to find "TTL=" in output that's been redirected to `NUL`. Remove that redirection so `FIND` gets something to search.

Your second problem is a logic error, where even if you execute the `||` clause, the other lines are executing too. You need to use an `ELSE` or another `IF` clause.

Finally, I think you're overcomplicating the processing of your list of IP addresses.

Try this, and see if it makes sense.

```
@echo off & setlocal

set /a counteron=0
set /a counteroff=0

for /f %%i in (%~n0.txt) do (
    ping %%i -n 1 | find "TTL=" >nul 
    if errorlevel 1 (
        set /a counteroff+=1
        echo %%i is offline.
    ) else (
        set /a counteron+=1
        echo %%i is online
    )
)

echo.
echo %counteron% machines are online.
echo %counteroff% machines are offline.
```

Comment: Actually you could replace `if !errorlevel! GEQ 1` by `if ErrorLevel 1` as they are equivalent, so no more need for delayed expansion...